# How do I install MS Visual C++ for python 2.7?

Tags: python-2.7, visual-c++, installation, canopy

I am using the Enthought Canopy IDE to run my python codes and I want to install MS visual C++. 
I downloaded the .msi  file from [here](https://www.microsoft.com/en-in/download/details.aspx?id=44266) and now can I just install VCForPython27.msi directly using the installation wizard? As far as I understand, I cannot do that(right?). But I don't understand what I have to do now to install this into the Canopy environment.

The site says use pip install but when I try

```
pip install VCForPython.msi
```

I am getting an error message saying that no matching distribution found for VCForPython.msi

I also tried converting the .msi to a .whl file and then trying to install but I am getting an error at

```
wheel convert VCForPython.msi
```

saying this is not a zip file. I am a complete beginner and I realize most of what I tried might be nonsense. Please tell me how to install VC into the virtual environment of Canopy.

PS. I am doing all this after opening 'Canopy command promt' from tools.

PSS. I have to install this because I want to get baseSphinx setup and [this](https://github.com/cmusphinx/pocketsphinx-python)
post says VC is a dependency. That does mean I have to install this right?

Answer (score 0):

> now can I just install VCForPython27.msi directly using the installation wizard?

Yes.

> As far as I understand, I cannot do that(right?).

Wrong. :) Could you point me to the instruction which gave you this wrong impression so that we can correct / clarify it?

> The site says use pip install

That's how you install a python package. Microsoft Visual C++ compiler is not a Python package. It is required in order to build some Python packages.

> VC is a dependency. That does mean I have to install this right?

Right.